# Why can gamma rays penetrate a thick layer of lead and why can't a beta particle penetrate a thin sheet of aluminum?

Tags: radiation, gamma-rays

This might be a stupid question, but, why is it that gamma rays are able to penetrate almost any barrier without question? We know that gamma rays are simply high frequency waves with massive amounts of energy. However, what processes can enable it to go through layers of bonded atoms of metals and just about anything else?

On another note, we know that beta particles can pass through paper but can not penetrate a thin layer of metal. What is different about the bonds of metal so that an electron can't squeeze through?

I assume it is because of the tightly bonded metallic bonds and the high volume of electrons that flow throughout the metal that causes this. However, if this is the case, what would a beta particle do if it is "rejected"? Would it join the flow of electrons in the metal, would it just stay on the same side of the sheet or would it rebound in the opposite direction due to the equal, opposite force exerted on it by the sheet?

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter could cite rationale for the downvote

Comment: Remember that beta particles (simply electrons) carry charge and mass, they experience electromagnetic forces that photons do not.

Comment: Gamma rays are photons. Gamma rays are uncharged particles, they do interact with solid matter, but relatively weakly. Beta rays are electrons. Beta rays are charged particles, they interact with matter quite strongly due to, e.g., Coulomb repulsion.

Comment: @Newton'scat Some common downvote reasons include: The question does not show any research effort; the question is unclear or not useful; etc.

Comment: You can look up the absorption coefficient for gamma rays (if you know the actual energy you are interested in) for a given material. This will tell you about the penetration depth. You will find that very dense materials such as lead can stop gamma rays, but (generally) the more energetic the ray the further it will penetrate (with the exception that some gamma rays at very specific energy can excite the nuclei and thus will have an absorption peak around those specific energies).

Comment: @Newton'scat the down vote is probably because your attempt and an explanation of the phenomena is just wrong. Of course, the point of this site is to answer questions, and it's a good question. It took Hans Bethe to answer it almost 100 years ago, and he was no slouch.

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> We know that gamma rays are simply high frequency waves with massive amounts of energy

All electromagnetic waves are built up by a confluence of photons, and photons are elementary particles. Low energy photons interact quantum mechanically with the electric and magnetic fields of solids. The gammas have very high energy and the only way they could interact to change their straight line track is by a direct hit. The probability of this is very small. (One has to study quantum mechanics and interactions of particles in order to understand the mathematics).

Beta particles are electrons and are charged so the probability of interacting with the solid is large in metals that are composed of atoms with many electrons, and much smaller in your thin paper example. Again to really understand what is going on one has to study in depth the subject.

You state:

> . However, if this is the case, what would a beta particle do if it is "rejected"? Would it join the flow of electrons in the metal, would it just stay on the same side of the sheet or would it rebound in the opposite direction due to the equal, opposite force exerted on it by the sheet?

It will depend on the quantum probability of interaction of the electron hitting a metal surface, there will be some probability for a reflection from the surface, but a number of interactions can happen between an electron and the atoms of the lattice, including loosing energy and being absorbed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Coulomb interaction has infinite range, a charge particle passing by a stationary charge interacts, no matter the impact parameter (classically). So a charged particle passing through matter interacts with a "sea" of atomic electrons, losing energy as it traverses the material.

The loss in a common material (and elements) is often quoted as $\frac{dE}{dx}$, and is available in tabular form. The density of electrons and the ionization energy are the dominate factors (along with the speed and charge of the particle).

For a typical beta electron, paper is not enough material to stop it, while a few inches of aluminum is.

Gamma rays are neutral, so they don't have a long range interactions, rather, they need to collide with a material. That interaction goes roughly as the square of the electric field strength, so heavy nuclei with large $Z^2$ make good shielding.

Of course there are many subtleties, which can be found in:

https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-passage-particles-matter.pdf

Comment: However, why is an aluminum enough to stop a beta particle? Is it because the element has a higher intrinsic density than paper?

Comment: Also, why are gamma rays often stopped by lead? Is it because the energy it carries  is transferred to too many atoms and just "fades"?

Comment: no, the gamma gets near a nucleus, where the electric field is strong, so $(Ze)^2$ dominates. Lead has a large Z, and it packs them in. Look up radiation lengths of various materials.

Answer (score 1):

You see that beta rays are electrons and moving electron loss their energy via interacting with the surrounding Matter, there is also a good probability that the electron would get scattered in different directions as it is passing through matter and also, moving charges with acceleration or deceleration losses energy by radiation of EM waves.
So, I have three ways that an electron losses energy. But, in case of gamma rays they do not lose their energy unless or until they transfer their energies to the electron in the atoms of the surrounding Matter. Hence, giving them more penetration power than beta rays.

And P.S. by the way this is not a stupid question. It's a good question "helps you understand the nature of interaction of particle and energy with matter", and empowers you with a better grip at reality once you understand the answer to why that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the encouragement. Welcome to the site as well!